# Recursively document R package

Tags: r

I'm trying to build my first package with RStudio.

I already had a project with R files and I just changed the project layout like this:

```
.
|-R
|---File
|---Physics
|---Plot
|---Utils
|-man
|-vignettes
|-DESCRIPTION
|-NAMESPACE
```

My DESCRIPTION file contains the following text:

```
Package: my-package
Title: Package title
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: person("Ben",
  "Me",
  email = "my@email.com",
  role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: blabla
Depends:
    R (>= 3.3.2)
License: file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Suggests:
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

All my functions contain roxygen comments. And when I use the Build/Document function in RStudio, it says:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))

Updating my-package documentation
Loading my-package
Writing NAMESPACE
Updating vignettes
Documentation completed
```

But the man pages and the NAMESPACE file remain empty.

If I Build&Reload the project, I have a `No man pages found in package` message.

So I guess the Document command was not applied correctly. If I put an R script with comments directly at the root of the R folder, it finds it. Is there a way to make RStudio explore recursively all my code folders or should I just put all my files at the root of the R folder (which is cumbersome for someone coming from the Java world...)?

Comment: Try the correct folder structure first. Also, this isn't an Rstudio issue.

Comment: So the correct folder structure is a flat structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) states that only the following folders are allowed (and have their own functions):

> The man subdirectory may contain a subdirectory named *macros*; this will contain source for user-defined Rd macros. (See User-defined macros.) These use the Rd format, but may not contain anything but macro definitions, comments and whitespace.
>
> The R and man subdirectories may contain OS-specific subdirectories named *unix* or *windows*.

Comment: Ok. That feels strange. It means that big packages have plenty of files in just one folder. Not easy to maintain IMHO.

Comment: @Ben You are free to use a sensible naming scheme for these files. E.g., check out how a big package like ggplot2 does it: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/tree/master/R